# Error with Heroku remote: /usr/bin/mate -w: /usr/bin/mate: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have been stuck on this for a while... Help would much be appreciated!

I am attempting to create a rails app and deploy to heroku. As noted in this step:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#deploy-your-application-to-heroku.

I create an app and see a success:

```
  |master| → heroku create big-services-ca

Creating big-services-ca... done, stack is cedar-14
https://big-services-ca.herokuapp.com/ | git@heroku.com:big-services-ca.git
Git remote heroku added
```

It looks successful. But when I run the command to see if it was, I see an error. I am not sure what is causing this.

```
  |master| → git config -e

/usr/bin/mate -w: /usr/bin/mate: No such file or directory
error: There was a problem with the editor '/usr/bin/mate -w'.
```

It also looks successful when I check it this way:

```
  |master| → git remote -v

heroku  git@heroku.com:big-services-ca.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:big-services-ca.git (push)
```

And not to my surprise, I am them unable to push to master:

```
To git@heroku.com:big-services-ca.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:big-services-ca.git'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  |master| → git config -e

/usr/bin/mate -w: /usr/bin/mate: No such file or directory
error: There was a problem with the editor '/usr/bin/mate -w'.
```

This command tries to open default text editor. In this context it is TextMate.
But it seems that you don't have it installed.
Just change your default editor and it will success

Comment: Thanks for your help! Do you see anything wrong with using this syntax:
 
`# Set my editor and git editor`
`export EDITOR=‘/usr/bin/subl’`
`export GIT_EDITOR='/usr/bin/subl'`

Comment: It is in my .bash_profile..... I wanted to make sure. I am having some really weird issues with Sublime 3. It loads completely glitched out and unusable. I had to revert to Sublime 2.

Comment: So, does it fix your problem?

Comment: i think u have tiks on the first phrase, i think u should user single quots instead